# React Native 0.62 Backhandler to go back and exit on a WebView

Tags: react-native

I am using the below code to make a React-Native mobile app to view a video chat website. App using `react-native-webview`. When I click the back button, the app asks to confirm, and when clicking yes App exits. I want to extend this to go back if web view has a history. If not exit the app.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";
import {
  PermissionsAndroid,
  ActivityIndicator,
  StyleSheet,
  BackHandler,
  Alert,
} from "react-native";

export async function requestVideoPermission() {
  try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
      {
        title: "Camera",
        message: "Need access to your camera ",
      }
    );
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      // Do nothing
      requestAudioPermission();
    } else {
      // Do nothing
      requestAudioPermission();
    }
  } catch (err) {
    // Do nothing
  }
}

export async function requestAudioPermission() {
  try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.RECORD_AUDIO,
      {
        title: "Mic",
        message: "Need access to your microphone ",
      }
    );
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      // Do nothing
    } else {
      // Do nothing
    }
  } catch (err) {
    // Do nothing
  }
}

const App: () => React$Node = () => {
  requestVideoPermission();

  useEffect(() => {
    const backAction = () => {
      Alert.alert("Hold on!", "Are you sure you want to go back?", [
        {
          text: "Cancel",
          onPress: () => null,
          style: "cancel",
        },
        { text: "YES", onPress: () => BackHandler.exitApp() },
      ]);
      return true;
    };

    const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
      "hardwareBackPress",
      backAction
    );

    return () => backHandler.remove();
  }, []);

  return (
    <WebView
      userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; XXX) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.96 Mobile Safari/537.36"
      automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
      source={{ uri: "https://my_url_here" }}
      startInLoadingState={true}
      allowsFullscreenVideo={true}
      allowsInlineMediaPlayback={true}
      renderLoading={() => (
        <ActivityIndicator
          color="blue"
          size="large"
          style={styles.flexContainer}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
};

export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  flexContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

This is the code part I am using to handle the back button event. Please tell me if anyone has the experience, to go back if web view has history, otherwise exit the app.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const backAction = () => {
    Alert.alert("Hold on!", "Are you sure you want to go back?", [
      {
        text: "Cancel",
        onPress: () => null,
        style: "cancel",
      },
      { text: "YES", onPress: () => BackHandler.exitApp() },
    ]);
    return true;
  };

  const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
    "hardwareBackPress",
    backAction
  );

  return () => backHandler.remove();
}, []);
```